# Yocto runs only one task inside at a time

Tags: linux, build, virtual-machine, embedded-linux, yocto

I have setup my development environment inside Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 14.04. My company doesn't allow me to run direct Linux Flavoured OS may be due to security reasons.

One thing I have observed is that in VM it only runs one task ast a time whereas if i run on my personal laptop it runs multiple tasks at a time.

Is there any way to configure poky in local.conf file for example or any other file for it to run multiple tasks at the same time. I have given more than 6 GB of RAM to the VM.

As it is running one task, build is taking a lot of time..

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bitbake task executor enquires for number of CPUs dynamically, so it seems that you might have allocated 1 cpu to your VM. You might be able to see CPUs with below command in VM

```
lscpu
```

You might want to allocate more CPUs. VirtualBox lets you do that

1. Stop virtual machine
2. Click settings-> click system -> click processor -> Change the number of procesors.

Comment: Thanks.. Modified the processor count to 4. I have now 4 tasks running parallelly